# Is it possible to summon zombies with lowered arms in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

(Version: 1.12.2)

I've been working on a map that includes NPCs, but I've been unable to find a way to create realistic human-looking NPCs without modifying the zombie texture. All is well in that sense, but now all the humans have their arms weirdly raised at all times.

Is it possible to customize zombies so that their arms are lowered? And if not, what are some alternatives to this?

Answer (score 1):

1.13+

I don't think it is possible to make zombies not raise their arms. I would suggest retexturing items that armor stands can hold/wear (boots, leggings, chestplate, helmet, sword, bow...) using CustomModelData to look like body parts/clothes and use [this](https://haselkern.com/Minecraft-ArmorStand/) website to summon them with a particular orientation/pose. This of course requires a resourcepack and some commands, but it is probably the option that gives you the most flexibility.

1.8-1.13

**The void of no knowledge.** Someone please fill it.

1.8-

Once upon a time there was a hostile "human" mob which could be summoned up until 1.8, and looked like the player. Using mods or external tools it may be possible to retexture it to work in later versions, but I'm not sure how. Obviously  in versions prior to 1.8 you can just use that. Anyone with information on that should edit it into this post.

Comment: This is impossible, since the version I'm using to create the map is 1.12.2. I am unable to use a newer version, as anything past 1.13 removes /testfor.

Comment: @kineticcrusher You didn't need testfor in 1.12 either. It was already obsolete years ago, at least since 1.9.

Comment: Fabian, testfor is useful for things like dialogue and map events. I've put endless effort into working out how the replacement, /execute, works, but to no avail. I just want to know if there's a way to do what I'm asking.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see the 1.12.2. CustomModelData was introduced in 1.13 so this method will not work for you, unfortunately, but maybe someone else will find it useful. Also, `/execute` is more flexible than `/testfor` *in my opinion*, and is in all the newer versions, so it is worthwhile learning. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Yep, it's no issue. I've seen plenty of videos of 1.12.2 (or earlier) maps having humanoid NPCs with no raised arms, however, so surely there is a way.

Comment: @kineticcrusher Regardless of the obsolescence of `/testfor`, you can implement a functionally equivalent command in 1.13 using `/execute if entity`

Comment: @kineticcrusher Please, consider learning how `execute` works, at least for replacing `testfor`.  Almost everything these days revolves around `execute`, so you need to know it.  Even in 1.9-1.12 days, `execute` is central to so many command contraptions that it becomes difficult to do anything complex without it.  You don't have to learn the entirety of `execute`, let alone memorize it, but you should learn the key concepts.

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if people could focus on answering my question. All I want to know is a way to summon a humanoid-like entity, and then I'll be on my way.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really know any way to do this for 1.12. However, if you could link one (or more) of those videos that would help us a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the custom npcs mod you could set the zombies job to "puppet" and manually lower their arms to whatever position you like. However it will stay in that position even if its attacking.